# Comparison function for sorting member vector with sort()

Tags: c++, sorting

i have a class like this:

```
class test
{  
    vector<expr*> _exprs;  

    bool cmp(expr* e1, expr* e2);   

    ExprManager* mg;  
}
```

and the Comparison function is:

```
bool test::cmp(expr* e1, expr* e2)  
{  
    return exprHight(mg, e1) < exprHight(mg, e2);  
}
```

then when i use the comparison function in sorting the _exprs(in another member function)

```
sort(_exprs->begin(), _exprs->end(), cmp);
```

The compiler report:

```
error: argument of type ‘bool (test::)(void*, void*)’ does not match ‘bool (test::*)(void*, void*)’
```

How to fix it? Thanks for advance.

Comment: That is not the *actual* class definition, is it? From your comments, I am guessing it has a destructor, but no copy constructor or assignment operator. Is that correct?

Comment: I defined a inner class which instantiated with the outer `mg`, and defined the operator() in this inner class. It works now.

Comment: that sounds to me like a needlessly complicated way to work around a broken class design ;) If your classes leak resources (or double-free them) when copied, you're going to run into similar problems with 90% of the standard library. You should fix the problem at the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to define a predicate for sorting is as a functor.

Make your class define the `operator()` to do the comparing, and you can just pass an instance of the class to `std::sort`.

So really, all you need to do is to define the class like this instead:

```
class test
{  
    vector<expr*> _exprs;  

    bool operator()(expr* e1, expr* e2);   

    ExprManager* mg;  
}
```

And then you can call `sort` like this:

```
sort(_exprs->begin(), _exprs->end(), test());
```

or, of course, use an existing instance of the `test` class, instead of constructing a new one. But you just pass in a class instance, and don't need to mention the member function at all.

If the sorting takes place in another member function (it looks that way from your reference to `_exprs`), write

```
sort(_exprs->begin(), _exprs->end(), *this);
```

One thing to note is that `std::sort`, like most other standard library algorithms, copies the predicate object, and so your predicate class must be able to handle copying safely (which your classes should always do *anyway*)

In short, the way to achieve this is to follow the "rule of three".

If your class defines a destructor, copy constructor *or* assignment operator, then it should almost certainly define all three.

If the compiler-generated copy constructor is used, it will simply copy your class' pointer members, so you will have two objects containing pointers to the same object.

If the class has a destructor which calls `delete` on that pointer, then that ends up being done twice. Which is an error.

If your class is intended to be copyable (and most of the standard library requires this), then you must define appropriate copy constructors and assignment operators to implement it safely (for example, copy the resource pointed to by the pointer, or use a smart pointer instead).

IF your class is *not* intended to be copyable, then you should define the copy constructor and assignment operators to be `private`, so that attempts to copy the class will result in a compile-time error, instead of runtime crashes.

You should *never ever* define a class which can be copied, but doesn't do so correctly. Either define the necessary copy constructor/assignment operator/destructors to *handle* copying, or make copying impossible by making copy ctor/assignment operator private.

Wrapping pointers to dynamically allocated memory owned by the class in smart pointers is a simple way to get copyability for free.

If the class contains only RAII objects, then you don't need to define a destructor at all, and so the rule of three doesn't require you to define copy constructor and assignment operator either.

Comment: @hailin: I edited my answer to better describe the proper solution to the double-delete problems you mentioned in comments.

Comment: You're spending a lot of time talking about copying of classes when the golden rule is that predicates should be _extremely_ cheap to copy :) And man, _that_ predicate _is_ expensive :) Remember that `std::vector`'s copy constructor is required by the standard to make a _deep_ copy!...

Comment: @mmutz: yes, predicates should be cheap to copy, but one *more* important rule is that they should be *safe* to copy. Given the OP's problems, it seems like he doesn't know how to achieve that. Once he understands how to make objects safely copyable, he should obviously make a cheaper predicate functor as well. :) First make it work, then make it fast. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `test::cmp()` *static*:

```
class test {
    // ...
    static bool cmp( expr * lhs, expr * rhs );
};
```

Alternatively, if `test::cmp()` *cannot* be static for some reason, you need to use (`boost::` or `std::tr1::`) `bind()` to bind the (implicit) `this` parameter of `cmp()`:

```
test * someInstance = this // other // something;
sort( _exprs->begin(), _exprs->end(),
      bind( &test::cmp,  someInstance, _1, _2 ) );
```

Comment: I tried this, but another compiler error happend- error: invalid use of member ‘test::vc_’ in static member function

Answer (score 0):

Use operator() and then pass '*this' as a Predicate to Sort algorithm.

```
class test
{  
    vector<expr*> _exprs;  

    bool operator()(expr* e1, expr* e2);   

    ExprManager* mg;  
}  

sort(_exprs->begin(), _exprs->end(), *this);
```

Whatever you pass as predicate must have public accessibility,

Comment: The definition of operator will be same as your previous `test::cmp`

Comment: Compiling is ok, but segment error happens(double free error). I traced with valgrind. The valgrind indicates that destruction is called somewhere in stl_algo.h.

Comment: check the function calls used in the `cmp / operator()` function. They might be freeing something

Comment: @hailin: then your code has another bug. This is the correct approach. `sort` doesn't call `new` or `delete` by itself, so anything that gets deleted happens as a result of objects going out of scope. Most likely, you've failed to follow the *rule of three*. Your class probably has a destructor, but no copy constructor. (The predicate object gets copied by `sort`, so it has to be properly copyable without leaking resources or bringing itself in an inconsistent state.

Comment: The class has destructor but no copy constructor. I think temporal object is created, and the other members(pointer type) are deleted when the sort() function exit.

Comment: Right. Ever heard of the "*rule of three*"?  You're violating that, and it causes your code to blow up in exciting ways whenever your objects are copied. It is easily fixable though.